# How to add more data into LocalStorage instead of overwriting it in contenteditable attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create contenteditable in div when user add something in it then it should add in local storage. but right now it is overwrite when add another data.

HTMl code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload="checkEdits()">
    <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
        Here is the element's original content
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="save my edits" onclick="saveEdits()" />
    <div id="update"> - Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>

    <h1 contentEditable="true">Your Name</h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS code

```
function saveEdits() {

    //get the editable element
    var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

    //get the edited element content
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

    //save the content to local storage
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

    //write a confirmation to the user
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";

}

function checkEdits() {

    //find out if the user has previously saved edits
    if (localStorage.userEdits != null)
        document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}
```

Comment: You can get the existing data from localstorage first and then append the new data to it and then set the localstorage

Comment: I do not think you are using localStorage right, you are adding an object to localStorage object. When you refresh your page, you data will be lost. If you want to store data temporarily, you can declare an array in your window object. simply  declare `let userEdits=[]` and when you add the change, write as follows `userEdits.push(newValue)`. to understand how to work with localStorage, please take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and also try to understand, localhostorage will not store your data as you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your saveEdits function to check is there anything saved on storage with the same key or not. To achieve it I will recommend you to use get and set item from API here some example how you can do it.

```
function saveEdits() {

  //get the editable element
  var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

  //get the edited element content
  var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

  //get previously saved 
  const previousEditsStr = localstorage.getItem('userEdits');

  // parse allready saved edits or create empty array
  const savedEdits = previousEditsStr ? JSON.parse(previousEditsStr) : [];

  // push the latest one
  savedEdits.push(userVersion);

  //stringify and save the content to local storage
  localStorage.setItem('userEdits', JSON.stringify(savedEdits));

  //write a confirmation to the user
  document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
}
```

Please be noticed that the memory here is limited and you need to take it under your control. For example you can limit previously saved comments.

Since we are saving an array thats men you need to change your reading part as well

```
function checkEdits() {
  const userEdits = localStorage.getItem('userEdits');

  //find out if the user has previously saved edits
  if (userEdits) {

    // here is the saved edits
    const comments = JSON.parse(userEdits);

    // showing previously saved message 
    document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = comments[comments.length - 1];
  }
}
```